# Why does this crash: stringByAppendingFormat

Tags: iphone, string, crash

My code crashes at this function (at the stringByAppendingFormat: with error `objc_msgSend() selector name: stringByAppendingFormat`).

This is that line:

```
    // imagesPath = ...iPhone Simulator/4.0/Applications/NUMBERS/Documents/images
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imagesPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%d.png", [[self.postsArrayID objectAtIndex:row] intValue]]];
```

Could it have something to do with the retaining of objects?

Thanks :)

Comment: Give more code. What is the type of `imagesPath`? (isn't it `NSArray*` or some other collection as plural in name suggests?) How do you initialize this variable?

Comment: As mentioned, `imagesPath` probably is not a `NSString` - try `NSLog(@"%d", [imagesPath isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);` to verify.

Comment: imagesPath is in fact an NSString, declared in header.

Comment: That it is declared as a `NSString` doesn't mean that you did assign a string to it. Another possibility is that its already been deallocated somewhere and not set to `nil`.

Comment: Well the line you copied isn't technically wrong, so more information is needed. What's the exception causing the break? what's logged for the crash? Also, you might wanna expand your code to several lines to see which method is causing the crash

Comment: Well, I tried stringByAppendingPathComponent instead, but that only made it get the same three images again and again. This code is getting run in the cellForRowAtIndexPath-method for tableViews.
Imagespath gets set in the viewDidLoad method. ` rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; imagesPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/images/"];`

Comment: And also created in .h with `NSString *imagesPath;`. I'll try to assign a (nonatomic, retain) property to it, too.

Comment: Hah! Setting a property and setting value using self.imagesPath =... fixed it. Obj-c is so hard to understand sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> rootPath =
> [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
> NSUserDomainMask, YES)
> objectAtIndex:0]; imagesPath =
> [rootPath
> stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/images/"];
```

> Hah! Setting a property and setting
>   value using self.imagesPath =... fixed
>   it. Obj-c is so hard to understand
>   sometimes...

The methods you used to set the get the paths are autoreleased, so when you tried to access them later they had already died. Using the self.imagesPath property will retain the data (you specified it as (nonatomic, retain) - so it will stay around until you release it (or assign anything else using the property accessor self.imagesPath = ....;

Apple's memory management guide is highly recommended, though it is still easy to fail after reading it a couple of times. :-)

Comment: I'll read it. Do you have a link?
I've had a couple of these crashes before :p

Comment: Sure, here's the link:  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html  I think they have an exact copy of it in the iPhone docs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a crash in `objc_msgSend()` implies the message being passed to the object (in this case, `stringByAppendingFormat`) is not specified for that object. [Quick googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=stringByAppendingFormat&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) reveals that many top pages for `stringByAppendingFormat` are quite dated, inferring the API has possibly been deprecated in favor of something else.

As a workaround, it would seem [`+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) would be a viable alternative for your use case.

Comment: [It's still there](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingFormat:), i don't see it being deprecated.

Comment: stringWithFormat won't work. I want to append a string to another string.

Comment: `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%d.png", imagesPath, [[self.postsArrayID objectAtIndex:row] intValue]]]];`

Comment: `stringByAppendingFormat` is not listed as a class method of NSString in the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_

Comment: @falconcreek I would say that this code wouldn't work (properly) either as `imagesPath` is still not what OP expects it to be. Of course, this might fix crash or move it somewhere else. And `stringByAppendingFormat` is an instance method as name suggests http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingFormat_

Comment: good points. `imagesPath` is likely nil. Only way to tell is if the rest of the code is added to the question. @Emil, set a breakpoint on the line that you posted and check that `imagesPath` is set to what you expect it to be.

Comment: No need, I forgot to assign a property and retaining it in h.
It's fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`? And surely `imagesPath` is not `........../NUMBERS/images`? Would it not be `................/<random ID>/images`?

Comment: I'm using that now. That doesen't matter, does it? I don't set that value, it was just to explain to you how it was built up.